# Can te root user access all directories and folders?

Tags: command-line, permissions, files, directory, root

Aŕe there files that the root user can't access, because earlier i was using the "du" comand and some files could not be accessed due to permissions

Comment: Without knowing which location(s) reported the access issue, it will be difficult to provide an answer. Some locations are better thought of as devices rather than storage locations. Access permissions also depend on the file system that's being used. Some temporary cache locations may also be blocked from access if they are marked as containing potentially sensitive data. This prevents anyone with `sudo` access from extracting passwords from transitory cache files, for example.

Comment: okay thanks for the feed back